# How JQuery objects assigned to a variable detect changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

(First of all sorry for my English) I can understand assigning JQuery objects that found by JQuery selectors, to a variable has better performance then using JQuery Selectors every time. The part that i cannot understand is how JQuery detects changes that are not manipulated by JQuery? Here is an example:

```
<div id="divState">First State</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
     var testElement = $("#divState");
     alert(testElement.text());//alerts "First State".
     document.getElementById("divState").innerHTML = "Second State";//Div has changed outside of the JQuery object.
     alert(testElement.text());//alerts "Second State"??? How a variable detects changes.
});
```

Comment: Thats not a change detection, it is simply reading the innerHTML, innerText, textContent properties on the underlying DOM element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it knows, but it doesn't know . . .

As **Blazemonger** points out, when you create a jQuery object, one of the items in the object is, essentially, just a pointer to the actual DOM element in the page.  So, like you show in your example, any time you inspect the properties of that object, it will inspect the element and show you whatever they currently are.  If they change in between checks, you will see the difference.

However, jQuery is not 100% smart . . . if you were to change something fundemental to the selector, it is not smart enough to know to update the collection of objects, without re-selecting them.  For example, look at this HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="similarDivs">Div 1</div>
    <div class="similarDivs">Div 2</div>
    <div class="similarDivs">Div 3</div>
</div>
```

If you run the following code against it:

```
var $mainGroup = $("#container");
var $subGroup = $mainGroup.find(".similarDivs");
console.log($subGroup);
```

. . . your console would show: `Object[div.similarDivs, div.similarDivs, div.similarDivs]`

But, if you were to follow that up with this code:

```
$mainGroup.children(":eq(0)").removeClass("similarDivs");
console.log($subGroup);
```

. . . your console would show: `Object[div, div.similarDivs, div.similarDivs]`

It is smart enough to see that the 1st `div` is no longer tagged with the "similarDivs" class, but it is not smart enough to know that, technically, that means that it should no longer be part of the `$subGroup` selection group.   Again, this is because the selector created a bunch of jQuery objects that point to all of the DOM elements that matched the selection criteria, **at a single point in time**.

The only way that you could get `$subGroup` to reflect the change in its collection is by re-running the selector:

```
$subGroup = $mainGroup.find(".similarDivs");
console.log($subGroup);
```

. . . resulting in: `Object[div.similarDivs, div.similarDivs]`

---

One of the biggest reasons that this is so important (apart from knowing that when you use selectors   :)   ), is because Javascript does **NOT** behave that way . . . if you were to write a similar set of functionality in JS, you would get different results:

```
var mainGroup = document.getElementById("container");
var subGroup = mainGroup.getElementsByClassName("similarDivs");
console.log(subGroup);
mainGroup.children[1].className = "";
console.log(subGroup);
```

That code would give you:

```
HTMLCollection[div.25dd58, div.25dd58, div.25dd58]
HTMLCollection[div.25dd58, div.25dd58]
```

. . . without needing to "re-select" the elements (**note:** it is also returning an `HTMLCollection`, not a jQuery `Object`, which clues you in to the difference in behavior).

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. So far i understand from the comments is; As @Blazemonger points out; returning object holds the pointer of the DOM element(s) not the attribute values etc.. So when i need a value of an element's attribute it follows the pointer of the DOM object and gets it.

Comment: More or less, yes.  The methods that jQuery provides "behind-the-scenes" are shortcuts for doing that very thing, but, you can also do it yourself, if you need to.  You can actually access the DOM object from a jQuery object using `[0]`, giving you access to native JS DOM methods.  So, if you are looking for the value of a text input, you can actually use `$someJqueryObject[0].value` (JS reference) or $someJqueryObject.val()` (jQuery reference).  However, there may also be some differences . . . using jQurey's `val()` on a `<select>` provides some additional logic, that JS's `value` does not.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, the jQuery object contains the DOM node, which is itself a live object. So changing the properties of the DOM node is reflected in the jQuery object.

If you were to [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) the jQuery object, you'd get the behavior you're expecting:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var testElement = $("#divState").clone(); // copy the object and store it
  alert(testElement.text()); //alerts "First State".
  document.getElementById("divState").innerHTML = "Second State"; //Div has changed outside of the JQuery object.
  alert(testElement.text()); //alerts "First State" again
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divState">First State</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` is NOT a different programming language. Its a library built on Javascript.

`testElement.text()` do not detect any change it simply picks the text of `testElement` and display to `alert`

Comment: That's not what he's asking.

Comment: @Blazemonger. jQuery do not _detect any change_.  And internally it do javascript only. Thats what I am trying to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain that testElement is just instructions on how to find the DOM element using good old JavaScript, which is faster than finding it via the jQuery selectors. 
So every time you work with it, it finds it anew.

Please correct me if I am wrong, that is just an assumption I have based on experience rather than knowledge.